# Passing arguments through a class inheriting from Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am learning how to use Tkinter to make GUI apps and I can not figure out why I can not pass a width and height argument through my class `__init__` function.

Edit: Sorry, got excited. What it's doing is telling me that I'm passing too many arguments. And no matter how I rearrange the parameters of the class `__init__` and `Frame` `__init__`, nothing changes. It's either too many, or not enough.

Edit_2: Alright, this runs without error. But it's still not resizing the frame.

Here is what I am working with.:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, height):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("App")
        self.grid()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = App(root, 300, 250)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code as listed works for me. Can you add the traceback of the exception you're getting to your question?

Comment: Hmm. It's running without error like this. I tore out a few methods used for widget placement to keep it short. But apart from it running, it's still not executing the task I'm trying to perform. For me, the window is barely visible when it inits. Then I have to resize manually.

Comment: You have to set main window size (`root` is main window) or frame size. But usin `self.width` will not change frame size. You have to use `self.config(width=new_width)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.width = width` doesn't change frame size because frame use different method to change size.

**First method**: you can use `Frame.__init__`.

```
Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
```

See:

```
from tkinter import *


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, height):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("App")
        self.grid()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = App(root, 300, 250)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Second method:** you can use `self.config(key=value)` or `self["key"] = value`

```
self.config(width=width, height=height)
```

or

```
self["width"] = width
self["height"] = height
```

See:

```
from tkinter import *


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, height):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        #self.config(width=width, height=height)

        self["width"] = width
        self["height"] = height

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("App")
        self.grid()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = App(root, 300, 250)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

BTW: `Frame.__init__` creates `self.master` and assigns `parent` to `self.master` so you can use `self.master` instead of `self.parent`

---

BTW: you can create window without `Frame`

```
from tkinter import *


class App(Tk):

    def __init__(self, width, height): # no need "parent"
        Tk.__init__(self) # no need "parent"

        self["width"] = width
        self["height"] = height

        # OR         
        #self.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
        #self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.title("App") # no need "parent"
        # no need self.grid()


def main():

    App(300, 250).mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Oh lovely!! Absolutely! Thank you! It works like a charm now!

Comment: `Frame.__init__` creates `self.master`  and you can use it instead  of `self.parent`

Comment: I had noticed when I was adding widget methods into this class that I didn't really have to designate the window, like `root` or `self.parent`, into the `.grid` function. Is that normal or is that because I'm using `Frame.__init__`?

Comment: command `root = Tk()` creates and displays main window. `Frame` is only "invisible" (without border) object to group other widgets. You can create `class App(Tk)` and add widgets directly to main window (without `Frame`)

Comment: Great! Are there any advantages or disadvantages by using `Frame`?

Comment: you don't need `Frame` at that moment. You will need `Frame` when you need to group widgets and show/hide frame with all widgets at once, or you need to use `pack()` inside one frame and `grid()` inside another frame (don't mix `pack` and `grid` in one frame or window). An when you need to create own widget - `class TwoButonsAndOneLabel(Frame)`

Comment: I had not even thought of combining widgets. Thank you! I'll be using the info you gave me right away! And I appreciate the explanations!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101636/discussion-between-acollection-and-furas).